# How to move block of images left and right provided they are in same container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a module for a website where i need to move list of images left and right while all of them being in same **container box**. Below is the dummy code which i was trying to work with.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nex").on("click", function() {
    var inpData = document.getElementsByClassName("boxh").length;
    var temp = 6;
    for (var counter = 0; counter < inpData; counter++) {
if(counter < 6 )
 {
      document.getElementsByClassName("boxh")[counter].style.display = "none";
      document.getElementsByClassName("boxh") [temp].style.display = "block";
      temp++;
  }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.boxh {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#b1 {
  background-color: coral;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
#b2 {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}
#b3 {
  background-color: coral;
  position: relative;
  left: 25px;
}
#b4 {
  background-color: coral;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
#b5 {
  background-color: coral;
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
}
#b6 {
  background-color: coral;
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
}
#b7 {
  background-color: coral;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
#b8 {
  background-color: coral;
  display: none;
}
#b9 {
  background-color: coral;
  display: none;
}
#b10 {
  background-color: coral;
  display: none;
}
#b11 {
  background-color: coral;
  display: none;
}
#b12 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: none;
}
#b13 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: none;
}
#b14 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: none;
}
#b15 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: none;
}
#b16 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: none;
}
#b17 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: none;
}
#b18 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: none;
}
#b19 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: none;
}
#b20 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<title>Code</title>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="boxh" id="b1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="boxh" id="b2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="boxh" id="b3">Box 3</div>
    <div class="boxh" id="b4">Box 4</div>
    <div class="boxh" id="b5">Box 5</div>
    <div class="boxh" id="b6">Box 6</div>
    <div class="boxh" id="b7">Box 7</div>
    <div class="boxh" id="b8">Box 8</div>
    <div class="boxh" id="b9">Box 9</div>
    <div class="boxh" id="b10">Box 10</div>
    <div class="box" id="b11">Box 11</div>
    <div class="box" id="b12">Box 12</div>
    <div class="box" id="b13">Box 13</div>
    <div class="box" id="b14">Box 14</div>
    <div class="box" id="b15">Box 15</div>
    <div class="box" id="b16">Box 16</div>
    <div class="box" id="b17">Box 17</div>
    <div class="box" id="b18">Box 18</div>
    <div class="box" id="b19">Box 19</div>
    <div class="box" id="b20">Box 20</div>
  </div>


  <button id="pre">Previous</button>
  <button id="nex">Next</button>

</body>

</html>
```

The requirement is such that on a single click of **next** button the Box with id **b1** should get the css property of

> display:none

and simultaneously the box with the id **b7** should get the css property of

> display:block

Hence it works like back and forth when user click ***next*** for **each single click** box with id *b1,b2,b3,b4* and so on will get the css property of

> display:none

while simultaneously all the boxes from forth with id *b7,b8,b9,b10* and so on will get the css property of

> display:block

I have also written the same code for previous button which i wrote for next but since in both the case logic is same if anyone can help me with any of them another one is easy to figured it out.
Only to note is that it should work with ***each single click of button*** on each single click one box should disappear and other to appear.

***PS:In above example box represents images***

Comment: why not use one of the millions of sliders out there that are already available if you are unable to write your own?

Comment: i am not familiar with it i am new to this

Comment: Use `slick carousel`, `bootstrap slider`.. Just go and check them.. It takes just 3 to 4 lines of code and 2 extra files to be included instead of all these.. :)

Comment: google jquery image slider - there is a plethora to choose from